# Linux if-else not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i write one linux code for Fibonacci series(0 1 1 2 3 5 8) but when i run its always showing me else statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This program will show series of Fibonacci numbers upto user input.

echo -n "Enter the number for Fibonacci series: "

read num

if [ $# = 1 ]
then

x1 = 0
x2 = 1

echo "The Fibonacci series for the number $num is: "    

for (( y=0;$y<num; y=$y+1 ))
do
echo -n "$x1 "
x2 = $(( $x2 + $1 ))
x1 = $(( $x2 - $x1 )) 

done

else

echo "Input is wrong" 

fi
```

if i remove if satement then i got error of line 10 and 11 and of for loop

Comment: You should use `-eq`, which compares integers algebraically. `=` is used for string comparison. Check out `man test` for more details.

Comment: I don't understand the logic to begin with. What is the expected argument on the command-line? And how does it relate to calculating fib for num?

Comment: expected argument is number like 4, 5 ,6 etc and loop with run upto that number and genrate that much numbers . for example if user enter 4 so user will get 4 fib numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're checking the number of arguments, but you either need to provide one argument or change it to check for zero arguments. Also you have a few spaces that will cause problems. You'll need to remove those. Lastly, as @bnaecker mentioned, you'll want to use `-eq` instead of `=` when comparing numerical equality.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This program will show series of Fibonacci numbers upto user input.

echo -n "Enter the number for Fibonacci series: "

read num

if [ $# = 0 ]
then

x1=0
x2=1

echo "The Fibonacci series for the number $num is: "    

for (( y=0;$y<num; y=$y+1 ))
do
echo -n "$x1 "
x2=$(($x2 + $1))
x1=$(($x2 - $x1)) 

done

else

echo "Input is wrong" 

fi
```

Comment: It may be working but logic is still inherently flawed. :}

Comment: @tink, true, but when answering questions on SO, I prefer to keep my answers minimal. With experience, programmers tend to improve and learn from mistakes on their own.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: i wasn't criticising your answer but the OPs reaction to it